# Can Apache POI extract the worksheet's unique rename-friendly "CodeName"-value?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

An Excel sheet apparently has a property called "CodeName" which is unique and stays the same even if the sheet is renamed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename

Is there any of getting the value of "CodeName" using Apache POI?

Comment: Not really clear what you wants to do with that `CodeName` but at least for Office Open XML (`*.xlsx`) it is stored in `/xl/worksheets/sheet[n].xml` as `<sheetPr codeName="TheCodeName"/>`. So yes, at least using `XSSFSheet` one could get this using low level underlying object `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet`.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, but the idea is to have an unique identifier that will stay the same regardless of sheet rearranging, renaming etc. The URI you are referring to refers to the sheet at index [n]. So if you were to rearrange the sheets, the same URI will point to a different sheet.

Comment: Yes, so your "solution" would be traversing through all `XSSFSheet`s in `XSSFWorkbook` until you find the one having `<sheetPr codeName="TheCodeName"/>` set. As said, not really clear what you wants to do with that `CodeName`. At least not because though it is not as variable as the sheet name is but also is not really fix since it **can** be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for Office Open XML (`*.xlsx`) the sheet's code name is stored in `/xl/worksheets/sheet[n].xml` as `<sheetPr codeName="TheCodeName"/>`. So at least using `XSSFSheet` one could get this using low level underlying object `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet`.

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

class ExcelGetSheetByCodeName {

 private static Sheet getSheetByCodeName(Workbook workbook, String codeName) {
  for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet)sheet;
System.out.println(xssfSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetPr().getCodeName());
    if (codeName.equals(xssfSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetPr().getCodeName())) {
     return xssfSheet;
    }
   } else {
    System.out.println("only XSSF implemented yet");
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx")); 
  Sheet sheet = getSheetByCodeName(workbook, "TheCodeName");

System.out.println("found sheet: " + sheet);

 }
}
```

Result:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ExcelGetSheetByCodeName 
Foo
TheCodeName
found sheet: Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed @AxelRichter! Thanks a lot :-) My intention is to use this in an Excel importer, where the user can map sheets and columns to elements in the target system. I was hoping to being able to keep the mapping even though the user renamed, added or deleted sheets. That's why I couldn't rely on index or sheet-name. Even though the codeName **can** be changed, it's a far less chance of it.